# Optimizing/restructuring Python for-loops to take advantage of Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization

Implementing a Local Search algorithm for the Quadratic Assignment Problem in Python with Numpy, I've found the use of for-loops to be problematic at best, given that CPython is very slow when it comes to heavy mathematical computation.

My code has a 3-level nested for-loop which iterates a solution (numpy ndarray), iterates over a mask (numpy ndarray), and iterates the solution again, then doing some computations that, and this is the troublesome bit, *may affect later iterations*.

My question is, is it even possible to somehow precompute this? With the nature of the problem, I'm not really sure. As the problem is a Quadratic, for small sizes it's acceptable, but over 100 elements results in *a lot* of iterations.

The code is as follows:

```
while has_improved and iterations < 100:
    for r in range(n):
        for b in dlb:
            if b: continue

            has_improved = False

            for s in range(n):
                move_cost = cost_fn_delta((flow, distance), solution, r, s)

                if move_cost < 0:
                    # Swap the indices
                    solution[r], solution[s] = solution[s], solution[r]
                    cost += move_cost

                    dlb[r], dlb[s] = False, False

                    has_improved = True

                iterations += 1

            if not has_improved:
                dlb[r] = True
```

Comment: if cost_fn_delta is a pure Python function, you could use the `numba` package to just-in-time compile this. Cython would be another option to compile your algorithm, which takes a bit more time to set up. It's hard to think about un-wrapping your for loops without some context of what the code is doing in simple terms, it's hard to reason with those non-descriptive variable names. It's also very likely this is impossible to un-wrap due to future iterations depending on what happened in all past iterations.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon `cost_fn_delta` is a Python function that uses Numpy matrix operations, so it's reasonably fast. I tried Numba in both functions, but it found some problems and couldn't JIT properly. Also, a brief explanation would be iterating over the solution, checking which "bit" of the solution is active, and if it is (dlb is a numpy boolean array, True means "ignore"), proceed to pair it every other "bit". Now... my original solution is wrong, as I'm iterating over all the dlb array, instead of just checking an element. So, thank you for making me understand my creation :p

Comment: numba will fail to compile the code if it includes function calls to non-Python code, which usually happens if you call numpy functions. If you re-wrote cost_fn_delta to use Python code only (and avoid numpy), numba should be able to JIT it.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Thank you for the brief explanation of Numba. Do you believe JITed python will outmatch numpy and "optimized maths"? I'll keep it in mind, but leave it alone for now, because I don't want another dep in the project. Thanks again. :)